# How to send data from my application to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have an application that makes analysis on maps . After making analysis I have new map in my application.

My application doesnt use QGis API. How can I send results back?

Should I construct object QgsVectorLayer  from my application and send new maplayer to QGis? 
What approach is better to use?

I want to create a plugin for QGis to work with my application and use TCP IP protocol. My application will be SERVER and QGis plugin CLIENT.

My application works with graphs. It accepts .mif files.
Could I construct QgsVectorMaplayer from points, lines and polygons?

Comment: Vague. Is your application a GUI program? The user loads a .mif file, does some work, and produces a new map (.mif?) file? Just get Qgis to read it in...